# Error 30700002: Smart contract's apply function not exported; non-existent; or wrong type

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, c++, wasm

I have written a smart contract and I want to start testing it, it contains an apply function, which currently checks for a transfer, and then calls the appropriate function:

```
 void mycontract::apply(account_name contract, account_name act)
 {
    switch(act)
    {
      case N(transfer):
        eosio_assert(contract == N(eosio.token), "MyContract | use eosio.token");
        on(unpack_action_data<eosio::currency::transfer>());
        break;
    }
  }
```

I also have the C version, which does not belong to the mycontract class:

```
  extern "C" 
  {
    [[noreturn]] void apply( uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action )
    {
      mycontract _mycontract(receiver);

      if(code == N(eosio.token))
      {
        switch(action) {

          case N(transfer):
            _mycontract.on(eosio::unpack_action_data<eosio::currency::transfer>());
            break;

          default:
            break;
        }
      }
      eosio_exit(0);
    }
  }
```

Finally, I try to add the contract to my local nodeos:

```
cleos set contract contractowner ../mycontract/ -p contractowner
```

I then receive the following error message, which I don't understand:

```
Error 3070002: Runtime Error Processing WASM
Error Details:
Smart contract's apply function not exported; non-existent; or wrong type
pending console output:
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this error message, or how I could go about debugging it further?

EDIT:
It also doesn't work if I use the macro:

```
EOSIO_ABI( eosio::mycontract, (on) )
```

Comment: what about  `EOSIO_ABI(mycontract, (on))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Based on the details you provided in the comments, I think the error might be coming from how you are compiling the code. You said you are running these commands:

```
eosiocpp -o mycontract.wasm *.cpp
eosiocpp -o mycontract.wast *.cpp
eosiocpp -g mycontract.abi mycontract.cpp
```

when you should actually be running these:

```
eosiocpp -o mycontract.wast mycontract.cpp
```

which will generate both the `.wast` and `.wasm` with just one command, and

```
eosiocpp -g mycontract.abi mycontract.hpp
```

which should receive the `.hpp` file which needs to be properly annotated with `//@action` and `//@abi table <table_name> <index_type>` directives for the command to generate the `.abi` successfully.

You can check [this simple contract files](https://github.com/andresberrios/token_ram_recovery) for a good example of the annotations and macros that are required for the compilation to work. Also note that you should give the specific file to the `eosiocpp` command, not just "all .cpp files" like you were doing with `*.cpp`.

**Previous answer:**

I would recommend not trying to write the `apply` function manually and instead use the `EOSIO_ABI` macro as shown [in this contract](https://github.com/andresberrios/token_ram_recovery/blob/master/token_ram_recovery.cpp):

```
EOSIO_ABI( eosio::token, (destroytoken)(destroyacc) )
```

This way you simply write a class that represents the contract and inherits from `eosio::contract`, and then define some actions inside of it as methods (keeping their names 12 chars or shorter) and then use the macro at the end like this:

```
EOSIO_ABI( <YOUR CONTRACT CLASS>, (<ACTION1>)(<ACTION2>)(<ETC>) )
```

This will create the `apply` function for you and everything will work nicely!

More info here: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/file-structure#section-the-eosio_abi-macro

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this also didn't work, giving the same error message. I wrote exactly this: `EOSIO_ABI( eosio::mycontract, (on) )`, outside of the eosio namespace.

Comment: Did it compile properly without errors when you run `eosiocpp`? Is your contract class defined inside the `eosio` namespace? I would recommend starting from a sample contract (like the one I linked) and modifying the code from there. Otherwise please share the whole code so we can see exactly what might be going wrong.

Comment: Yes the contract class is defined in the `eosio` namespace, and yes it compiles without errors when I run `eosiocpp`. The commands I use to compile are: `eosiocpp -o mycontract.wasm *.cpp`, `eosiocpp -o mycontract.wast *.cpp`, `eosiocpp -g mycontract.abi mycontract.cpp`

Comment: @PhillipHamnett I updated the answer in response to your comment

Comment: Hey Andres, thanks for your updated answer. This sort of worked. First of all, in your answer you say that you should compile with `-o mycontract.wasm`, do you not mean `-o mycontract.wast`? I tried that and it did stop the error message (replaced it with a different one though). Do I understand correctly that the contract must all then be written in a single .cpp file? Even if multiple different classes are used? I didn't see this written anywhere in the documentation, if you could point me to somewhere where I can read that I would appreciate it! Thanks again

Comment: Philip, you are right, I had a typo in the wasm extension, it was supposed to be wast, I updated the answer now, thanks! About your followup question: You don't need to write everything in a single file, you can include other files using `#include "other.cpp"` and define other classes there, but when you compile using `eosiocpp` you should point it only to the main cpp file, unless you use `#include "other.hpp"`, since then you would also need to point it to the cpp files for the implementation, and the `*.cpp` would work well I think.